# how to write a dplyr::filter function

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr filter function  source code ,i can't get,when I click filter(),
source code is UseMethod(), when I debug either.nothing appeard;

**my test code :**

> filter(irirs,Sepal.Length>7.1)

so I try to write my own function

**first version :**

```
   filter<-function(data,condition){
attach(data)
r<- data[which(condition,)]
detach(data)
return (r)
}
```

It works  ,when I use system.time() to compared dplyr:filter  and mine:filter, mine loose,spend much time than dplyr;

**second version:**

```
   filter<-function(data,condition){
r<-with(data,data[which(condition),])
return (r)
}
```

It report errors , Sepal.Length not found.

I kwnow is condition param'problem,
if I  use with(irirs,irirs[which(Sepal.Length>7.1),])  directly ,it works, but I need a own filter function

I have two  question :

- a. how to write a effective filter or fix my second  version code's problem.
- b. how to read function source code  like usemethod("func")

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

```
myfilter1 <- function(data, condition) {
  do.call(subset, list(data, substitute(condition)), envir = parent.frame())
}
myfilter1(iris, Sepal.Length > 7.1)

myfilter2 <- function(data, condition) {
  eval.parent(substitute(with(data, data[condition, ])))
}
myfilter2(iris, Sepal.Length > 7.1)

library(gtools)
myfilter3 <- defmacro(data, condition, expr = {
  with(data, data[condition, ])
})
myfilter3(iris, Sepal.Length > 7.1)
```

### Read R source code associated with an S3 generic

To read the source R code for the methods of an S3 generic `f` first list the methods:

```
methods(f)
```

and then if `f.x` is one of the methods listed enter its name without parentheses into R:

```
f.x
```

or if that does not work (which would be the case if there is a * after the name in the `methods` output) then

```
getAnywhere("f.x")
```

If the code is in package p on CRAN then we could google for *cran p* and download its source from the package's CRAN home page or find it on github by googling for *cran github p* and look at the source on the github web site.

### Performance

Regarding performance this is what I get on my PC:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gtools)
library(microbenchmark)

f1 <- function() {
  len <- 7.1
  myfilter1(iris, Sepal.Length > len)
}
f2 <- function() {
  len <- 7.1
  myfilter2(iris, Sepal.Length > len)
}
f3 <- function() {
  len <- 7.1
  myfilter3(iris, Sepal.Length > len)
}
fd <- function() {
  len <- 7.1
  filter(iris, Sepal.Length > len)
}

microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), fd())
```

giving the following.

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval cld
 f1()  399.2  433.70  497.133  482.00  518.85 1362.6   100  b 
 f2()  301.4  326.15  374.078  364.50  407.65  579.1   100 a  
 f3()  302.4  330.65  375.650  352.25  397.15  623.0   100 a  
 fd() 1791.5 1948.60 2166.466 2117.35 2262.65 3443.7   100   c
```

`myfilter2` and `myfilter3` have about the same mean times and both are faster than the other two.

Comment: besides I have got a problem on these filter function ，`len<-7.1   myfilter2(iris, Sepal.Length > len)   ` ， error for  object len not found , what should i fix this bug

Comment: Good point. Have fixed `myfilter1` and `myfilter2`.  They previously had problems with `f <- function() { len <- 7.1; myfilter1(iris, Sepal.Length > len) }; f()` but that and your example should work now.  `myfilter3` already handled these cases.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use `eval` `parse`, `text` in `subset` to write your own `filter` method

```
my_filter <- function(data, condition) {
    subset(data, eval(parse(text = condition)))
}

my_filter(iris, "Sepal.Length > 7.1")
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
#106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
#108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica
#110          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica
#118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
#119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
#123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
#126          7.2         3.2          6.0         1.8 virginica
#130          7.2         3.0          5.8         1.6 virginica
#131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9 virginica
#132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
#136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3 virginica

my_filter(mtcars, "cyl == 6")

#                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#Merc 280       19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#Merc 280C      17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#Ferrari Dino   19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

---

As far as your second question is concerned it is answered here :

[How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function)

Comment: thanks very much ,but i don't like character paramter ,is useful ,but  is not elegant  when i tidyr my data  ,  i just want  `my_filter(mtcars, cyl == 6)` this type

Answer (score 0):

thaks for  @G. Grothendieck  answer,

i compared  my version 1 filter,and `@G. Grothendieck`'s `myfilter2` and `myfilter1` and dplyr::filter ,

i use system.time() to compare them ,  my version 1  is the lowest efficiency ,and `myfilter2' is best ,

each func  execute `10000` times,use`func(irirs,Sepal.Length>7.1)`
this is time spend table:

```
  # func_name                 time_spend(s)
  # my version 1::filter         15.706          
  #  dplyr:filter                 6.108
  #    myfilter1                  1.648
  #    myfilter2                  1.229
```

time_spend  is system.time()  's elapsed

i didn't test myfilter3  because of i only want use base package to achieve my goals

Comment: Have added a performance section to the end of the my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse` options

```
library(dplyr)
my_filter <- function(data, condition) {
    data %>%
         filter(!! rlang::parse_expr(condition))
  }

my_filter(mtcars, "cyl == 6")
#   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#4 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#5 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#6 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#7 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

---

Or if we want to pass a unquoted expression, use `enexpr`

```
my_filter <- function(data, condition) {
        data %>%
              filter(eval(rlang::enexpr(condition)))
       }
my_filter(mtcars, cyl == 6)
#   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#4 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#5 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#6 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#7 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```